# Running a command as another use with different permissions

Tags: linux, grub2

I use a heavily locked down Linux system with GRUB's built-in verified boot mechanism. Consequently, I have to sign the kernels, GRUB modules, and configuration files in `/boot` every time I want to muck around with it (which is fairly often). Signing them requires that I used GPG and originally I couldn't get it to load my private key until I learned that I needed to use `sudo -E`.

I can sign the files, but I get a flood of this warning:

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on configuration file `/home/user/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

I want to make this go away by preserving the environment variables (as I already do) while making GPG think that "safe permissions" are on the configuration file. I don't want to move my GPG key to root's folder. Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add an ls -l /home/$USER/.gnupg for us please?  I think that may shed some light on the issue.

Comment: @Daniel The reason why GPG is throwing that error is because a user (root) other than the owner of those files (me) is accessing them. They are all owned by me and are all rw-------.

Comment: I could suggest changing the permissions on gpg.conf world readable -- that file doesn't need to be read blocked.  Or make a copy of it, as outlined in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this option, from `gpg`'s man page? I found it searching that page for "unsafe" (sounded familiar, probably from browsing)

```
--no-permission-warning
       Suppress  the  warning  about  unsafe  file  and  home directory
       (--homedir) permissions. Note that the  permission  checks  that
       GnuPG  performs are not intended to be authoritative, but rather
       they simply warn about certain common  permission  problems.  Do
       not  assume that the lack of a warning means that your system is
       secure.

       Note that the warning for unsafe --homedir permissions cannot be
       suppressed in the gpg.conf file, as this would allow an attacker
       to place an unsafe gpg.conf file in place, and use this file  to
       suppress  warnings about itself. The --homedir permissions warn‐
       ing may only be suppressed on the command line.
```

Or maybe make a root folder copy of some gpg files, just for checking signatures?